# In solvent extraction from plant cells, what is the static organic solvent film formed?

Tags: solvents, extraction

I am researching the mechanisms behind solvent extraction of oil from microalgal cells, and it is stated in one paper that in the process of transferring the lipid out of the cell, the solvent-lipid complex must diffuse through a 'static organic solvent film', which is supposedly formed from 'the interaction between organic solvent and cell wall' and 'surrounds the microalgal cell and remains undisturbed by any solvent flow or agitation'.

Attached is the diagram from the paper which shows how the solvent-lipid complex moves out of the cell, the dashed perimeter is the static film.

[image: Mechanism of solvent-lipid complex movement]

Here's the link to the paper if it helps: Halim, R.; Danquah, M. K.; Webley, P. A. Extraction of oil from microalgae for biodiesel production: A review. *Biotechnology Advances* **2012,** *30* (3), 709–732. DOI: [10.1016/j.biotechadv.2012.01.001](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.biotechadv.2012.01.001).

I am looking for an explanation with more details on why this occurs or any sources of information. I have had a search online, but there seems to be surprisingly little on the underlying processes of solvent extraction (for biodiesel production) despite its popularity.